# How can I force the use of a local package for a dependency?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

Say I'm running:

```
python -m mymodule
```

The module 'mymodule' has 3 dependencies: moduleA, moduleB and moduleC

I want to run mymodule BUT use another independant local package as the reference for moduleC, not the default path moduleC is assigned to.

So 'mymodule' uses 'moduleC', but I want it to use another version of moduleC that I personally have stored in another directory.

For instance:

```
python -m mymodule --force_dependacy_moduleC ~/Desktop/independent/localmoduleC.tar
```

I don't know if that makes sense but I wrote it as clear as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module lookup occurs based on your module search path, which you can override using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. For example, if `moduleC` is installed in `/some/other/directory/moduleC.py`, you could run

```
PYTHONPATH=/some/other/directory python -m mymodule
```

and `python` would first look in `/some/other/directory` for any module before searching the default directories.

Note that Python doesn't really support *using* multiple versions of modules installed in different directories in the same process. If you only wanted to use the specific version of `moduleC` for `mymodule`, but use the system-wide version elsewhere in the same script, you would have to install  the two versions of `mymodule` under different names instead.